# Chart not displayed after second set of data added

Tags: javascript, grails, anychart

This is part of a Grails application. The user clicks a button to create an API. They are sent to another page where they fill in some data and click an execute button. Once the api is done executing they are redirected to this page (list.gsp), which has a chart at the top of it. It is a bar chart that displays the data. The chart should display one set of data, then when a second api is executed the same chart should redisplay two/both sets of data.

What's happening is on my laptop the chart disappears after the second api is executed. On the other developers laptop who modified this code it displays fine. I am totally stumped on this one. I even had them zip up their project and send it to me. I ran theirs with the same results. We are running the same version of java (7)and grails (2.2.5). Any pointers appreciated!

```
 <%@ page import="foo.Api" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'default.api.label', default: 'Api')}" />

        <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
        <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/latest/anychart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/css/latest/anychart-ui.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#list-api" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
        <div class="nav" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></li>
            <li><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.button.execute.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="container" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

    %{--<tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">--}%
    <script >

        anychart.onDocumentLoad(function(){
            %{--var data = [--}%
                %{--["Cheapest", ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "cheapestPrice")}, 100, 175],--}%
                %{--["Highest", ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "highestPrice")}, 200, 250],--}%
                %{--["Range", ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "rangePrice")}, 300, 400],--}%
                %{--["Average", ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "averagePrice")}, 500, 600],--}%
                %{--["Median", ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "medianPrice")}, 700, 800],--}%
                %{--["Avg/50", ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "avg50")}, 900, 1000],--}%
            %{--];--}%

            var data = [
                    ["Cheapest"],
                    ["Highest"],
                    ["Range"],
                    ["Average"],
                    ["Median"],
                    ["Avg/50"]
            ];

            data.forEach(function(d){
                <g:each in="${apiInstanceList}" var="apiInstance">
                    if(d[0] == "Cheapest"){
                        d.push(${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "cheapestPrice")});
                    } else if (d[0] == "Highest"){
                        d.push( ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "highestPrice")});
                    }else if (d[0] == "Range"){
                        d.push( ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "rangePrice")});
                    }else if (d[0] == "Average"){
                        d.push( ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "averagePrice")});
                    }else if (d[0] == "Median"){
                        d.push( ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "medianPrice")});
                    }else  if (d[0] == "Avg/50"){
                        d.push( ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "avg50")});
                    }
                </g:each>
            });

            // create mapping list on one data set
            var dataMappingList = anychart.data.mapAsTable(data);


            // map x and value from the data set
            //compares every 2 apiInstances
            for(var i=0; i<dataMappingList.length; i+= 2){
                var colChart = anychart.column(dataMappingList[i], dataMappingList[i+1]);

                colChart.title("Top Flight Search Statistics");
                colChart.container("container");
                colChart.draw();
            }

        });

        %{--anychart.onDocumentLoad(function() {--}%
            %{--var data = anychart.data.set([--}%

                %{--["Cheapest", ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "cheapestPrice")}],--}%
                %{--["Highest", ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "highestPrice")}],--}%
                %{--["Range", ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "rangePrice")}],--}%
                %{--["Average", ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "averagePrice")}],--}%
                %{--["Median", ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "medianPrice")}],--}%
                %{--["Avg/50", ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "avg50")}],--}%
                %{--<%--  This is an example of changing the color of one bar in the chart ["Peter", 13000, 16500, "#5cd65c", "#009933", null, {enabled: true}],  --%>--}%

            %{--]);--}%
            %{--// create an instance of a chart with data--}%
            %{--var chart = anychart.column();--}%
            %{--var series = chart.column(data);--}%
            %{--chart.title("Top Flight Search Statistics");--}%
            %{--// pass the container id, chart will be displayed there--}%
            %{--chart.container("container");--}%
            %{--// call the chart draw() method to initiate chart display--}%
            %{--chart.draw();--}%
        %{--});--}%
        </script>
    %{--</tr>--}%
    <div id="list-api" class="content scaffold-list" role="main">
        <h1><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
        <g:if test="${flash.message}">
        <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
        </g:if>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <g:sortableColumn property="origin" title="${message(code: 'api.origin.label', default: 'Origin')}" />
                    <g:sortableColumn property="destination" title="${message(code: 'api.destination.label', default: 'Destination')}" />
                    <g:sortableColumn property="departureDate" title="${message(code: 'api.departureDate.label', default: 'Departure Date')}" />
                    <g:sortableColumn property="returnDate" title="${message(code: 'api.returnDate.label', default: 'Return Date')}" />
                    <g:sortableColumn property="cabin" title="${message(code: 'api.cabin.label', default: 'Cabin')}" />
                    <g:sortableColumn property="cheapestPrice" title="${message(code: 'api.cheapestPrice.label', default: 'Cheapest $')}" />
                    <g:sortableColumn property="highestPrice" title="${message(code: 'api.highestPrice.label', default: 'Highest $')}" />
                    <g:sortableColumn property="averagePrice" title="${message(code: 'api.averagePrice.label', default: 'Average $')}" />
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <g:each in="${apiInstanceList}" status="i" var="apiInstance">
                <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "origin")}</td>
                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "destination")}</td>
                    <td><g:formatDate date="${apiInstance.departureDate}" /></td>
                    <td><g:formatDate date="${apiInstance.returnDate}" /></td>
                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "cabin")}</td>
                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "cheapestPrice")}</td>
                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "highestPrice")}</td>
                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "averagePrice")}</td>
                </tr>
            </g:each>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="pagination">
            <g:paginate total="${apiInstanceTotal}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is the rest of the data displaying correctly?  Are there any javascript errors on your page (check your developer console)?  Can you provide a simplified example so that people here may be able to help track it down faster?

Comment: The console reports that the line below is missing a right parenthesis.                                        d.push( ${fieldValue(bean: apiInstance, field: "highestPrice")});

Comment: I also don't know if that double loop is even valid inside a grails gsp file.

Comment: The error is only reported the second time through the loop. The first, third and fourth times there is no error. I am convinced the error is meaningless. This is simply a matter of "it works for her, why doesn't it work for me?"

Comment: I found the issue. For the chart to display both sets of data the parameters feeding the chart have to be the same. If one is different the chart doesn't render. This is okay in my case but finding out how to get over that hurdle would still be nice.